# How to Convert number to date

Tags: sql-server-2008

How should I convert number to date?

for example:-

I would like to enter number as 31, it should find which all months has date as 31 and it should show out put as below for current year.

```
Date           Day
31-01-2013     Thursday
31-03-2013     Sunday
```

And how should I convert number to date.

Comment: Why is your question tagged [sql-server-2008]? Your question is somewhat unclear and there is no mention of SQL Server in your question.

Comment: @MartinLiversage the tag is letting people know what database they are using. DateTime functions change for each database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want to do, but if you create a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) first then it's a very simple query:

```
select [Date], [Day]
from dbo.Calendar
where YearNumber = 2013 and DayNumber = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`day()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) function to compare the day in your date column to the value that you provide. Then you can use [`datename()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) to get the weekday:

```
declare @val int = 31

select dt, datename(dw, dt)
from yourtable
where day(dt) = @val
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a27b3/5)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7789)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
declare @Day int;
set @Day = 31

select D.D,
       datename(weekday, D.D) as DOW
from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) as M(M)
  cross apply (select dateadd(day, 
                              @Day - 1, 
                              dateadd(month, 
                                      M.M - 1, 
                                      dateadd(year, 
                                              year(getdate()) - 1, 
                                              cast('00010101' as date))))) as D(D)
where day(D.D) = @Day
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/7789/0)**:

```
|          D |       DOW |
--------------------------
| 2013-01-31 |  Thursday |
| 2013-03-31 |    Sunday |
| 2013-05-31 |    Friday |
| 2013-07-31 | Wednesday |
| 2013-08-31 |  Saturday |
| 2013-10-31 |  Thursday |
| 2013-12-31 |   Tuesday |
```